# Как оставить свою верстку на Wordpress, при этом чтоб с админки можно было изменять только тексты и картинки?

Tags: wordpress

Суть вопроса описана в заголовке.

Пересмотрел кучу уроков, видео и тд. Переделать готовую тему не подходит. Рыться во всех этих файлах врагу не пожелаешь.

Возможно-ли оставить свою верстку сайта (разбив его на header, footer и тд.), чтоб из админки можно было менять только тексты и изображения своего слайдера. И если возможно, то как?

Comment: Что такое "макет"? Тема? Какая - из оф каталога или самописная кривая поделка, в которой нет возможности изменять слайдер из админки ? Но  при этом файлы тему трогать нельзя? Нда,  диллема :) .....  А "рытья" никого не нужно. И кучу мусорных "уроков", "видео" и тп смотреть тоже не нужно. Нужно читать документацию. http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2 https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC

Comment: Документацию читал. Там описана иерархия файлов и начальная разбивка своей темы на header, footer и тд. Но суть вопроса не в этом. Какой код нужно вставить вместо текстов и изображений в собственной верстке, чтоб их можно было менять в админке? В документации этого нет.

Comment: Так всё-таки файлы темы можно изменять? Для того чтобы добавить функционал.

Comment: У меня сейчас есть просто сверстанные с 0 страницы. Если я разобью их по файлам, получится тема для wordpress, в которой ничего нельзя будет изменить. Я же пытаюсь узнать, как изменить верстку так, чтобы из админки wordpress можно было менять тексты, картинки и тд.

Comment: Если ты "разобьёшь по файлам" - нифига хорошего у тебя не получиться.Без обид, но это видно по запросам. Возьми лучше готовую тему из репо и сделать к ней дочку со своей вёрсткой. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Возможно-ли оставить свою верстку сайта (разбив его на header, footer и тд.), чтоб из админки можно было менять только тексты и изображения своего слайдера. И если возможно, то как?

Нужно написать админ-страницы для хранения данных слайдера в БД, а в [шаблоны](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) темы добавить функции вывода слайдера. Образец админки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другой вариант - использовать готовый плагин слайдера, вставив его функции в шаблон