# Как написать админ-страницы Wordpress для хранения данных в БД?

Tags: wordpress

Суть вопроса описана в заголовке. Где можно найти информацию для написания админ-страниц wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вот [Как создать собственную страницу настроек для темы в админке WordPress](http://www.onwordpress.ru/stranicu-nastroek-temy-v-adminku-wordpress.html)

Не скажу насколько хороший мануал - употребление "шаблон", а не "тема" жутко коробит, говорит о не компетенции "писателя". Но код наверняка откуда-то скопирован и на первый взгляд как раз то, что нужно, учитывая [прошлый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620317/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD).

Только надо учитывать, что пост 2013г. Код наверняка ещё более раннего происхождения. Поэтому функции стоит сверять с [кодексом](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/).

Comment: Большое спасибо, но раз вы пишите про не компетенцию "писателя", то где можно найти источники этой информации? Может какие-то зарубежные документации? В русскоязычном интернете очень мало толковой информации.

Comment: Эти писатели обычно копипастят. и рерайтят. Иногда с нормальных источников, иногда с таких, же как они (что чаще бывает). Но код как правило не страдает от этого, если только не побит. В любом случае - там даны функции и по ним можно (нужно) читать мануалы и гуглить

Comment: Но раз под уникальные темы приходится писать админ-страницы под wp, то по времени и силам получается тоже самое, что и написать сайт на фреймворке, я правильно понял?

Comment: Что быстрее - съесть суп или лапшу? :) Не надо ничего писать в 99% случаев.Даже никакого смысла нет в "уникальных темах", тем более без опыта и понимания АПИ и архитектуры ВП. Не только нет смысла, но даже вредно и опасно, особенно если это для клиента. Делай дочернюю тему к подходящей и репо и используй готовый плагин слайдера (тоже из репо) и всё будет хорошо

Comment: Если б не было смысла в уникальных темах, я бы не пытался разобраться во всем этом. Когда пишешь сайты на заказ и тебе уже дают фотошоповский дизайн сайта, надо как-то сохранить его и прикрутить к wordpress.

Comment: Во первых не надо браться за такие вещи, если нет опыта и знаний. Во вторых - из psd нарезать картинки и в дочернюю тему их. С этим справиться любой маломальски знающий php и css. И это к тому же правильно по многим причинам.

Comment: Во-первых не все psd-макеты можно перенести одними картинками, во-вторых с такими рассуждениями нужно вообще ничем не интересоваться, ничего не учить, а пользоваться только тем, что уже готово. Это не правильно. Как тут придет опыт и знания, когда пояснения скрыты за семью печатями?

Comment: Неправильно - это браться за постройку пирамид, не имея опыта и знаний строки простых сооружений. Дочерние темы - это не просто правильно. Это не только ступенька к пирамидам. Это базис, фундаментальные знания. Сколько раз мне приходилось потом переделывать сайты после таких самописных опасных и корявых велосипедов..

Comment: Я не хочу изобретать велосипед. Я возьму базовую тему с http://underscores.me/ . Просто хочу сохранить внешний вид страниц, без плагинов построения страниц и тд. Благодарен вам за помощь)

Comment: underscores.me конечно не плохой вариант, но это таки велосипед. Причем для профи. Не велосипед (+ проще. качественнее, безопаснее) - это дочерние темы к темам из оф.репо.

Comment: Раз разработчики Wordpress разрешают создавать свои темы и даже есть документация, значит в этом есть смысл. Насчет качественнее не соглашусь. В плане фронтенда дочерние темы ограничены родительскими, А насчет "проще"... мне не нужно "проще", мне нужно будет выполнять поставленные задачи.

Comment: Удивительно что-то запрещать в опенсорсе :) А поставленные задачи должны выполнять плагины, а не тема. Вот это и есть один из аспектов "качественнее". Про же безопасность в таких самописах вообще говорить не приходится. Подстава клиентам на каждом шагу. Плавали, знаем. Ок. лано, пожалуй достаточно толочь воду в ступе.

Answer (score 0):

Очень неплохо на русском языке расписано здесь: https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html